# How can I enforce a maximum number of related records in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Put another way, is it possible to have an aggregate [constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-constraints.html)? For instance, if I wanted to have a maximum number of tags on a post or a maximum number of users in a group?

Imagine a `post_tags` join table with a `post_id` column and a `tag_id` column. How can I enforce that a given `post_id` only appears in this table a limited number of times, e.g., 5?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot accomplish what you want with a constraint, but you can with a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). Specifically an after statement trigger. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ebd31e0edec91da6ac5bbf628c44b7ab).

```
create or replace function max_post_check() 
  returns trigger
 language plpgsql 
as $$
declare
    
    max_posts_allowed integer = 5;
    over_allowed_id   integer;
    number_of_posts   integer;
begin 
     select post_id, count(*) 
       into over_allowed_id 
          , number_of_posts
       from post_tag          
      group by post_id
     having count(*) > max_posts_allowed
     limit 1;
 
     if number_of_posts is not null then 
         raise exception 'Post_id %, with % references exceeds application limit of %',over_allowed_id,number_of_posts,max_posts_allowed;
     end if;  

     return null;  
end;
$$;

create trigger max_post_check_ais
    after insert or update on post_tag
    for each statement
        execute function max_post_check();
```

Comment: you shouldn't check *every* count. Just the one being touched: `if (select count(*) from post_tag where post_id = NEW.post_id) > 5 then raise exception 'Post_id %...', NEW.post_id)'; end if;`

Comment: You could do that, but it requires a ROW level trigger. You could also of course use `referencing new as ...` clause on the trigger definition, but then you would have to interate each item in the reference array collection.

Comment: Of course for each row. Time complexity of running individual queries is O(1) * number of rows affected (which is typically/always 1 - posts are not added wholesale) so O(1) vs running your "all in" query which is O(n) once, so O(n). Ergo, your query does not scale.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jianheMark/plpgsql/main/trigger_count_demo.sql @Bohemian do you think this is ok?

Comment: Could it be accomplished with a function definition and then putting a call to that inside the constraint?